# Knife Azure Create VM fails - Waiting for WinRM

Tags: azure, chef-infra, knife

I'm new to Chef and I am trying to create a Windows Azure VM using knife-azure.

The command I am using is:

```
knife azure server create
  --azure-dns-name 'grusscheftest3'
  --azure-source-image 'bd507d3a70934695bc2128e3e5a255ba__RightImage-Windows-2012-x64-iis8-v14'
  --winrm-user 'myuser'  
  --winrm-password 'password1' 
  --template-file 'windows-chef-client-msi.erb' 
  --azure-service-location "North Europe"
```

The output of this is:

```
..........
Waiting for virtual machine to reach status 'provisioning'..........vm state 'provisioning' reached after 2.26 minutes.
Waiting for virtual machine to reach status 'ready'..........................vm state 'ready' reached after 6.48 minutes.
.
DNS Name: grusscheftest3.cloudapp.net
VM Name: grusscheftest3
Size: Small
Azure Source Image: bd507d3a70934695bc2128e3e5a255ba__RightImage-Windows-2012-x64-iis8-v14
Azure Service Location: North Europe
Public Ip Address: 168.63.56.119
Private Ip Address: 10.76.184.43
WinRM Port: 5985
Environment: _default

Waiting for winrm on 168.63.56.119:5985

Waiting for remote response before bootstrap.ERROR: No response received from remote node after 0.0 minutes, giving up.
ERROR: RuntimeError: Command execution failed.
```

I have tried this on two image files
    bd507d3a70934695bc2128e3e5a255ba__RightImage-Windows-2012-x64-iis8-v14
    bd507d3a70934695bc2128e3e5a255ba__RightImage-Windows-2008R2-SP1-x64-iis75-v5.8.8

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: did u configure the winrm in ur windows machine..??

Comment: According to azure WinRM is already configured and in Azure it has an endpoint (on the correct port).  I have checked the port is open by using telnet.  I thought with the recent Azure Chef annoucements that the images were ready, I'm now thinking that they are not.

Comment: @grahman actually . i faced similar issue , what i did was configured the winrm settings .

Comment: @mohan how did you apply the settings?  The VM that knife has created I can't connect to it to run the commands below.  RDP doesn't even work!

Answer (score 2):

Initially , in most of the system winrm is configured .

```
winrm quickconfig -q
```

It will give winrm is already configured. After this try out the following

```
winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}  
   -->if your system is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and older keep it "300" , else "1024"

winrm set winrm/config @{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}

winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}

winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}

winrm set winrm/config/client/auth @{Basic="true"}
```

I think this might solve your problem , and make sure that port is 5985 and 5986 is active(opened)

Comment: I think I've found the problem!  The vm did not have remote desktop enabled so I added this using the Azure Portal and added the Remote Desktop endpoint.  Then I remoted into the machine and ran "winrm quickcondig -q".  This stated that WinRM was not setup to allow remote access to the machine.  It then updated the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to allow this.

Comment: However, when I imaged this machine and tried using knife azure create it still failed even though WinRM was correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for this error might be:

1.Your target node winrm is not properly configured

2.5985 and 5986 ports of are not opened on your target machine

3.This is one of the cases where beginners usually get struck at.I faced the same issue.When you run knife bootstrap windows winrm command on machine in your private network.You have to pass command as below.

> knife bootstrap windows winrm hostname -x Domain\\username -P password
>   -r role[role_name]

Comment: The bootstrap command is separate to the Knife Azure Server Create command, I am trying to get this working within the one command (as I understand it should do).